# Error inserting image to openGL in gluBuild2DMipmaps

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to insert image in openGL using Textures. I'm using Ubuntu Linux. This is my main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Images/num2.c"

using namespace std;

void display() {
glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
/* create the image variable */
GLuint gimp_image;

/* assign it a reference. You can use any number */
glGenTextures(1, &gimp_image);

/* load the image into memory. Replace gimp_image with whatever the array is called in the .c file */
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gimp_image.bytes_per_pixel, gimp_image.width, gimp_image.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gimp_image.pixel_data);

/* enable texturing. If you don't do this, you won't get any image displayed */
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

/* draw the texture to the screen, on a white box from (0,0) to (1, 1). Other shapes may be used. */
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

/* you need to put a glTexCoord and glVertex call , one after the other, for each point */
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2d(0.0, 0.0);
glTexCoord2d(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2d(0.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2d(1.0, 1.0);
glTexCoord2d(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2d(1.0, 0.0);
glEnd();

/* clean up */
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDeleteTextures(1, &gimp_image);
glFlush();
 }


 void init (void) {
/*  select clearing (background) color       */
    glClearColor (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

/*  initialize viewing values  */
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition (400, 300);
    glutCreateWindow ("MineSweeper");
    init ();

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

The code for num2.c file that I've used is [here](http://pastebin.com/q4vD4mMk)

On compiling using following options : `g++ temp.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut` I get the following errors:

```
temp.cpp:23:46: error: request for member ‘bytes_per_pixel’ in ‘gimp_image’, which is   of non-class type ‘GLuint {aka unsigned int}’
temp.cpp:23:74: error: request for member ‘width’ in ‘gimp_image’, which is of non-class type ‘GLuint {aka unsigned int}’
temp.cpp:23:92: error: request for member ‘height’ in ‘gimp_image’, which is of non-class type ‘GLuint {aka unsigned int}’
temp.cpp:23:138: error: request for member ‘pixel_data’ in ‘gimp_image’, which is of non-class type ‘GLuint {aka unsigned int}’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `num2.c` file declares `gimp_image` as a struct with several members, but in your `display` function, you create a `gimp_image` of type `GLuint`. This local variable shadows your global variable, so when you try accessing `gimp_image.bytes_per_pixel`, it looks in the local variable (an integer) rather than the global variable. Since integers don't have members, it gives you an error.

Comment: I changed the Gluint gimp_image to image and then things worked fine. Thank you.